# Get all rows in addition to number of all rows for pagination using json and ajax in Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, pagination

I want to get 10 rows from database and count them all for pagination. It works when I don't use ajax however there is a problem in encoding jason and sending it to the view.

My code in controller:

```
$datas = model::take(10)->get();
$dataCount = model::all()->count();
$datas = $datas->put('dataCount', $dataCount);
return json_encode($datas);
```

And my code in view:

```
.complete(function(datas)
{
    data = JSON.parse(datas.responseText);
    data_count = data.dataCount;
    delete data['dataCount'];
    count = data.length;

    for(key=0; key<count; key++)
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

When I delete data['dataCount'], the data object gets undefined, but when I delete $datas = $datas->put('dataCount', $dataCount), it works however I want to use count of all rows to create a pagination.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the json_encode? Just return $datas

Comment: Again it's just like before, it gets undefined completely when I delete that element.

Comment: Why you dont use paginate() method?

Comment: paginate method is for paginating only, however I want to send both paginating and the main data using json and ajax. I want to show 10 records, and number of pages needed. But the problem is when I merge them together. It doesn't work when putting it in a new variable and delete it in javascript. When I delete the specific item, it gets undefined completely.

Comment: O sorry, it doesn't get undefined when I delete the item in javascript but when I put a new item into the records fetched from database in controller, it got undefined in javascript.

Comment: By the way it has data inside the variable, but data.length is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something to do with the Eloquent collection serialization. Try not including arbitrary data to the collection. Try something like this:

```
$datas = model::take(10)->get();
$dataCount = model::count();

$resp['data'] = $datas->toArray();
$resp['dataCount'] = $dataCount;

return json_encode($resp);
```

It will return your data array in a json attribute and your count in other.

Comment: Note that `model::all()->count()` Will execute `SELECT * FROM modelTable` then count the number of results in the collection. You should do `model::count()` instead. That will do `SELECT count(*) FROM modelTable` which is a much more efficient way to get the count.

Comment: Updating my answer. Thank you for the tip.